GAP won't run command line options as specified in documentation
TL;DR: I am trying to run a Hello world command in GAP from the command line. I write gap -c Print("Hello world"); into the command prompt as per the documentation, and it simply opens GAP, but does not run the Hello world program. How do I get this to work?

I am trying to, from the Command Prompt on Windows, run a Hello World program in GAP from the command line.
The GAP documentation in Section 3.1 states:

When you start GAP from a command line or from a script you may
specify a number of options on the command-line to change the default
behaviour of GAP.
[...]
-c gapcode
tells GAP to execute the given GAP code as if it was entered into a temporary file which then is processed together with the other files given to GAP (see the explanation at the end of this list for further details on how filenames are processed).

So, in order to do this, I should be able to run gap -c Print("Hello world"); from the command prompt.
However, when I do this, GAP simply runs and does nothing.
It turns out that

During a GAP session, one can find the current values of command line options in the record GAPInfo.CommandLineOptions (see GAPInfo (3.5-1)), whose component names are the command line options (without the leading -).

so I ran such a command in GAP and the output confirms it did not receive my command:

Alt text: GAPInfo.CommandLineOptions shows c := ""
So, I must be doing this wrong. How do I get this to work?
